# Java, accessibility of anonymous inner private interface

Tags: java, eclipse, interface, strategy-pattern, anonymous-inner-class

I have implemented the strategy pattern inside the class to perform an execution according to the input. It works fine and is called by a simple way.

```
public class MyObject {

private final Object input;
private final Strategy strategy;

public MyObject(final Object input, final Strategy strategy) {
    this.input = input;
    this.strategy = strategy;
}

private interface Strategy {
    public void execute(final Object input);
}

public static final class FirstStrategy implements Strategy {
    @Override
    public void execute(final Object input) {...}
}

public static final class SecondStrategy implements Strategy {
    @Override 
    public void execute(final Object input) {...}
}
```

---

```
new MyObject(null, new MyObject.FirstStrategy());
```

As soon as I type `new MyObject(null, new MyObject`, the Eclipse IDE's complete assistant offers me to implement the interface which is **private**.

[image]

Selection of this item results in the erroneous structure suggesting me to create a class `Strategy` since it's not visible to the other classes.

```
new MyObject(null, new MyObject.Strategy() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Object input) {}
});
```

I know how anonymous inner types work and why it happens. This one is easily solved changing the visibility of the interface `strategy` to **public** - but it is against to what I want. I insist to not let the client use any other implementation except the ones I give him through `FirstStrategy` or `SecondStrategy`. Is there a way to get rid of this autocomplete suggestion to implement a private interface and expose only the limited implementations using the anonymous inner type at the same time?

Comment: It is just a *suggestion*. You're free to ignore it, type a `.` and get the two implementations as suggestions instead.

Comment: You cannot prevent other callers who can see the interface from creating an implementation of it. You could however make the Strategy interface an abstract class, and then make the ctor package private

Comment: @Andreas: Personally, I don't mind type `.` and go on. I don't want to offer to another user to implement the private interface, that's not possible :D

Comment: @flakes: I know that well. However, the private static abstract class may be the way.

Comment: Make the Strategy interface `private` is really counter intuitive.   
Clients have to be able to program by interface as he/she uses your strategy implementation.

Comment: (Comment moved from my answer) I wonder why you're going to all this effort. What is it that you're trying to prevent people doing in the `Strategy` implementations that means it is worthwhile stopping them using their own implementation of the interface? It's not like they'd be able to access any private state or methods of the `MyObject` class.

Comment: @Andy Turner: I understand your point and admit my requirement might sound silly. I only wonder of the way to provide a predefined set of choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only to allow specific subclasses, provide constructor overloads for those specific subclasses:

```
public MyObject(final Object input, final FirstStrategy strategy) {
  this(input, (Strategy) strategy);
}

public MyObject(final Object input, final SecondStrategy strategy) {
  this(input, (Strategy) strategy);
}

private MyObject(final Object input, final Strategy strategy) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I am aware of this straightforward way. It's perfect for a short number of strategies but impractical for 10+ ones. Anyway, thank you for the answer :))

Comment: Is it *actually* impractical, or do you mean "it's more work than I was hoping"? This, or similar static factory methods, or an enum (if none of the strategy implementations require member variables), are the only way you can make sure that *only* the implementations you want can be passed in.

Comment: I don't mind to make it up for 10+ even 20+ strategies. Obviously, I would like to find the most "correct" and simple way. Using enum sounds like a good idea actually.

Comment: Not very logic requirement but you have my vote anyway as it addresses finely it.

Answer (score 0):

A private interface can only be implemented within the `MyObject` class. If the client tries to implement it in some other class, it won't compile. And even if the client creates their own `Strategy` class, `MyObject` constructor will not accept it.

Regarding this autocomplete suggestion - it's just not correct.

Comment: I said: `I know how anonymous inner types work and why it happens.` I ask for the way to provide a limited set of choices.

Comment: @Nikolas then you should address this question to Eclipse developers, because it's the IDE specific behaviour. For example in the IntelliJ IDEA [there are no such suggestions](https://i.imgur.com/JyrZQEb.png)

Comment: Great idea! I didn't think of IDE specific behavior first. :))